# How to preserve keys with capital letters read from a config-file with configparser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

When reading out a config file with python's `configparser` package, all key names are lowercase strings. Does anybody know how to read the strings preserving capital and uppercase words?

For example:

```
$cat config.cfg 
[DEFAULT]
Key_1 = SomeWord
KEY_2 = Another Word

$ python3
>>> from configparser import ConfigParser
>>> cf = ConfigParser()
>>> cf.read('./config.cfg')
['./config.cfg']
>>> print(cf.defaults())
OrderedDict([('key_1', 'SomeWord'), ('key_2', 'Another Word')])
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you'll explain in more detailed way, there will be more answers.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate.. It was the word "case" that didn't come to my mind.. ^.^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, all keys are automatically transformed to lowercase during read/write operations. This is mentioned in the last sentence of [the Quick Start section of the `configparser` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#quick-start).

To not have this effect you can set your parsers' [`optionxform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.optionxform) (a callable) to simply return the `option` rather than transform it to lowercase:

```
>>> from configparser import ConfigParser
>>> c = ConfigParser()
>>> c.optionxform = lambda option: option
>>> c.read('./config.cfg')
['./config.cfg']
```

Now keys are preserved as they were defined:

```
>>> c.defaults()
OrderedDict([('Key_1', 'SomeWord'), ('KEY_2', 'Another Word')])
```

Of course you can customize this to your liking, if, for example, you wanted all keys to uppercase you could set that in `optionxform`:

```
>>> cf = ConfigParser()
>>> cf.optionxform = lambda option: option.upper()
>>> cf.read('./config.cfg')
['./config.cfg']
>>> cf.defaults()
OrderedDict([('KEY_1', 'SomeWord'), ('KEY_2', 'Another Word')])
```